# How to force docker-compose to wait for one build to complete before building another service when using multi-stage builds?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I've got this structure:

```
my-app/
├─ my-submodule/
│  ├─ .git
│  ├─ Dockerfile
│  ├─ ...
├─ .git/
├─ .gitmodules
├─ docker-compose.yml
├─ Dockerfile
├─ .dockerignore
├─ ...
```

`my-app` includes a submodule that needs to be compiled before building the main app.

I would like to use docker-compose to build `my-app`, **it would need to first build `my-submodule` using its Dockerfile, then build the main app.**

I'm using multi-stage builds:

submodule/Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu AS my-submodule
WORKDIR /my-submodule
COPY . 
# ...
```

./Dockerfile:

```
FROM my-submodule AS my-app
WORKDIR /my-app
COPY . .
# ...
```

./docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  my-submodule:
    image: my-submodule
    build:
      context: ./my-submodule
      target: my-submodule
  my-app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: my-app
    image: my-app
    depends_on:
      - my-submodule
```

My `.dockerignore` ignores `my-submodule`, because its content should already be copied when building `my-submodule`, so there's no need to copy it again when building `my-app`.

Currently, when running `docker-compose build` for the first time, I'm getting

> => ERROR [my-app internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/my-submodule:latest                                                                                                                                                 0.4s

...

> failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed

The next time I run it, it builds fine because `my-submodule` has been built.

*How can I prevent docker-compose from building `my-app` until `my-submodule`'s image exists?*

Comment: Compose doesn't have a facility to do this.  Is the submodule actually runnable (what's its `CMD`?) or can you combine the two parts together into a single Dockerfile?

Comment: `my-submodule` isn't runnable, compiling it generates some files and library that are linked when building `my-app`. I could use a single Dockerfile, the thing is that multiple different apps have `my-submodule` as a dependency, I would prefer `my-submodule` to have its own dockerfile so it can be built by itself and avoid duplicating the code in every app that needs to build `my-submodule`